# Create a comment and tag another GitHub issue, does owner of that linked GH issue/PR get notified?

Tags: github

For example: in the image below, this user mentioned several issues, such as #44597.

- Does the owner of that issue (#44597) get notified?
- What if it's a PR that is referenced - does the owner of the linked PR get notified?

I think the answer is no and I should tag the person if I want to give them a heads up.

[image]